# C++ ofstream: save to a new line instead of overwriting old one

Tags: c++, ofstream

So im writing a simple program where you input 2 numbers and the product of those 2 numbers is printed out in the console, i have used ofstream to log the numbers successfully. My question is how do i make it print to another line every time the program runs, i probably dont make complete sense so here is kind of what i mean:

1st run:

```
Number 1: 10  Number 2: 45
```

2nd run:

```
Number 1: 10  Number 2: 45
Number 1: 50 Number 2: 13
```

i want it to write to a new line and not replace the first basically, any help would be greatly appreciated, i gather it is quite easy but i cant find a method.

Comment: Show the code you've got so far. Make a [mcve]. Perhaps you want to [append](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) to the log file?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you want to do is *append* to the file, not overwrite it.  In the constructor of `ofstream`, or when you call `open`, pass `std::ios_base::app` as the second argument.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this small example for appending the next execution to the log file:

```
#include <fstream>      
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main () {

  std::ofstream ofs;
  int number1, number2;
  ofs.open ("test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
  cout << "Number1: ";
  cin >> number1;
  cout << "Number2: ";
  cin >> number2;
  cout << "Sum of two numbers: " << number1 + number2;
  ofs << "Number1: " << number1 << " Number2: " << number2 << std::endl;

  ofs.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should just pass the arguments to the constructor instead of calling `open()` after default constructing. In general it's better to initialize objects to the desired value instead of default constructing and assigning later on. Also, there's no need to call `close()` since the destructor will automatically close the file.

Comment: Yes. Thank for your suggestion.